# Endless loop with assember

Tags: windows, loops, x86, dos, assembly

OK, I'm new to PC Assembler. I"m trying to write an program, but it won't stop looping. I'm guessing the ECX register is being modified? How can I fix this? Thanks.

```
DATA SECTION
;
KEEP DD 0                   ;temporary place to keep things
;
CODE SECTION
;
START:
MOV ECX,12
TOPOFLOOP:
PUSH -11                        ;STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
CALL GetStdHandle           ;get, in eax, handle to active screen buffer
PUSH 0,ADDR KEEP            ;KEEP receives output from API
PUSH 5,'bruce'                  ;5=length of string
PUSH EAX                    ;handle to active screen buffer
CALL WriteFile
XOR EAX,EAX                 ;return eax=0 as preferred by Windows
LOOP TOPOFLOOP
ENDLABEL:
RET
```

Answer (score 2):

In most x86 calling convention, including the `stdcall` convention used by Windows API functions, ECX is a caller-save register -- the called function is not required to make sure the value of the register is the same when it returns as when it was called. You have to save it somewhere safe in your own code.

Comment: Whether that is true or not, as an assembler programmer, you must take care that having acquired values of interest into the registers, that a subroutine call doesn't destroy them (registers are precious, and the subroutines need to use some of them too).  One way to do this is have conventions about register management (e.g., STDCALL) which hint what you have to do (e.g, if you use subroutines following the STDCALL convention, and ECX is important to you, you need to save it across the subroutine call).

Comment: ... a common method for saving a register across a subroutine call is to push it into the stack (this depends on the stack not containing anything of interest to the subroutine; if it does, you need another trick).   The usual scheme is PUSH REG\CALL SUBR\POP REG, in OPs code REG==ECX.